# Emmet snippet for 43 divs

Tags: html, emmet

I'm trying to put 43 divs with different ID's with emmet. If i do it by hand it's gonna take me forever! Well look at the code

```
<div class="inlineform cb">
              <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" />
              <label for="c1"><span></span>Check Box 2</label>
           </div>
```

I want emmet to change **id="c1"** and **for="c1"** to **c2, c3, c4** etc up to **43**. How can I do that? I didn't find any how to for this specific snippet. Thank you :)

Comment: Do you really need an empty `span` with no attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a different `name` for each input, so I've changed it to match the `id`:

```
.inlineform.cb*43>input[type=checkbox]#c$[name=c$]+label[for=c$]>span+{Check Box $}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! When i'll have free time i'll read much better the documentation! Emmet is life saver